# php access to cookie after it is set via href

Tags: php, cookies

I have two `PHP` scripts.
The first checks if there is a cookie and if not executes the second script.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['OlafErnstPhotographyNudeWarning'])){
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['OlafErnstPhotographyNudeWarning'];
} else {
    header("Location: adult.php");
}
```

The second `PHP` script creates the cookie and goes to a different `PHP` site:

```
<a href="<?php header("Refresh:1; url=women.php");?>" OnClick="SetCookie('OlafErnstPhotographyNudeWarning','anycontent','-1')">Continue</a>
```

Everything works but I always have to reopen the site in browser in order to get the result. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: really not sure what you're trying to do here nor what the problem is

Comment: in `"OnClick="...` the first quote is unwanted

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve? The second cookies you will get only after clicking on your 'Continue' link.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. Goto http://www.olafernst.com/women.php.
There you can see if you click on EXIT it goes to the maintenance screen (looks similar but that's correct). If you would click on CONTINUE it goes to the women.php after refresh only. If there would be a way to avoid the flickering effect or any other solution that would be great.
Thanks again

Comment: That's not what the `header()` function does. It doesn't belong mixed within a HTML link.

Comment: I tried the header outside as well. It works but the flicketing is annoying. The  otyer thing I did was href directly to the php side but then I need to click twice to get there